# Elasticsearch fails to start with index and alias names need to be unique error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch integrated into my app for a long time now. Since, a couple of days ago I get this weird behaviour. My elasticsearch instance is not starting. Following is the error I get. I tried to uninstall and reinstall elasticsearch but, that didn't work.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: index and alias names need to be unique, but alias [orders_development] and index [orders_development] have the same name

Comment: Did you upgrade elasticsearch recently? 2.x and upwards are a lot stricter about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same issue locally (macOS El Capitan).  I resolved it by opening Activity Monitor and killing all java processes.

Comment: Man, you saved my day. I issued this on HighSierra, but the trick was easy. thanks